# Why date format changes on adding it to the string?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, sequelize.js, date-formatting

I am trying to fetch data from one db and putting into another.

Array of objects I fetched from database 1:

```
{ id: 474951,
  language: 'ENGLISH',
    created_at: 2022-02-13T14:44:01.000Z,
    updated_at: 2022-08-02T03:40:04.000Z,
    deleted_at: null,
    published_at: null
   },
  { id: 531134,
    language: 'ENGLISH',
    created_at: 2022-05-09T15:09:39.000Z,
    updated_at: 2022-08-02T03:40:03.000Z,
    deleted_at: null,
    published_at: null,
 }
```

Then I am putting this data to another db.

```
updatedData.map((row) => {
      
      const keys = Object.keys(row).toString();
      let values = ``;
      Object.values(row).map((data) => {
        
        values = `${values},${data}`;
      });
console.log(value);
      const query = `REPLACE INTO meta.${table} (${keys})
            VALUES(${values});  `;
   
      promises.push(
        db2DBRW.query(query, {
          replacements: {},
          type: QueryTypes.REPLACE,
        })
      );
    });
```

This code is failing and reason being in the value date format is changing itself.

Value variable for first map iteration comes out to be:

```
,474951,ENGLISH,6800000022427207,Sun Feb 13 2022 20:14:01 GMT+0530 (IST),Tue Aug 02 2022 09:10:04 GMT+0530 (IST),null,null,null
```

I am not able to understand why is date working weirdly when its in fetched database object it has different format and on adding it in a string format its value changes.

Comment: Dates will only preserve their formatting if stored as a string, otherwise they're generally stored as an integer, usually counting the seconds or milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: Also, use prepared statements instead of template literals

Comment: not clear, can you please give code example?